# attach database not work in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite (works in System.Data.Sqlite)

Tags: database, sqlite, immutability

The following code works in System.Data.Sqlite. Recently I switched to Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, it gives error "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database"

```
            using (var command = _conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                var qAttach = @"ATTACH DATABASE 'file:C:\mydata\address.db?immutable=1' AS address";
                command.CommandText = qAttach;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes: `@"ATTACH DATABASE 'file:C:\mydata\address.db?immutable=1' AS address"` or `"ATTACH DATABASE 'file:C:\\mydata\\address.db?immutable=1' AS address"` - you don't need to use an interpolated string (`$""`) here.

Comment: Thank you Dai! I have corrected in my question, to use @"" instead of $"", it is still not working.

Comment: Does it work if you use a normal file-name instead of SQLite's own URI syntax? Have you verified that the file exists on-disk and your process has NTFS ACL permission to read the file? Do any other processes have the same file open or locked in exclusive mode? Can you open the file using the SQLite command-line programs?

Comment: Normal file-name works. But I need to specify ?immutable=1 so I used URI syntax. Need to specify immutable=1.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you **MUST** use [URI Filenames](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html#coreuriqueryparameters) in the `Data Source` keyword in order for the [SQLITE_OPEN_URI](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_open_autoproxy.html) flag [to be set](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v8.0.0/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteConnectionInternal.cs#L31-L34) and enabled for use with the `ATTACH` statement.

The [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings#keywords) should probably call this out but doesn't; it only says: `This keyword also supports URI Filenames`.

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=file:foo.db?immutable=true";
using (var conn = new Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    var attachCommandSql = "ATTACH DATABASE 'file:bar.db?immutable=true' as bar;";
    var attachCommand = new SqliteCommand(attachCommandSql, conn);
    attachCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
    //...Additional Statements Below
}
```